# Xamarin Forms editors in ListViews are losing focus whenever I type something on iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms, editor

I have a ListView in Xamarin Forms that has custom ViewCells with editors in them. I have a function subscribed to the editors' TextChanged events that checks the text for newlines and if it finds any, it removes them and unfocuses the editor. It works properly on Android, but on iOS, the editor gets unfocused whenever I type *anything*, not just newlines. How do I fix this?

The XAML for the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Partylist.Views.ChecklistPage"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">
    
     ...

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!--Main layout of the page-->
        <StackLayout>
            <!--ListView of the checklist items-->
            <ListView x:Name="ChecklistView"
                      HeightRequest="300"
                      HasUnevenRows="true"
                      ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <SwipeView>
                                <!--Swipe from the right to make some options 
                                appear-->
                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Invoked="OnDelete"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                   Text="Delete"
                                                   BackgroundColor="#ff418b"
                                                   IsDestructive="true"/>
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>

                                <!--This is the actual content-->
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Padding="20,5"
                                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <ContentView Content="{Binding ItemCheckbox}"/>
                                    <ContentView Content="{Binding ItemEditor}"
                                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </SwipeView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
             ...

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Partylist.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ChecklistPage : ContentPage
    {
        // Struct for items on the checklist.
        private struct Item
        {
            public Editor ItemEditor { get; set; }
            public CheckBox ItemCheckbox { get; set; }
        }
        // Create a list of contact structs to populate the ListView.
        ObservableCollection<Item> items;
        // Flag for when an item is added to the list.
        bool itemAdded = false;

        ...

        // Override for OnAppearing().
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            // Makes the page appear.
            base.OnAppearing();
            // Set the page's title to be the name of the selected list.
            Title = App.selectedList.Name;
            // Make a toolbar item appear to access the Main Checklist
            // unless we are already there.
            if (App.selectedList.ListFile.Name.EndsWith(".mchec"))
            {
                ToolbarItems.Remove(MainChecklistButton);
            }
            // Set the binding context of the page to itself.
            BindingContext = this;
            // Start the timer for the tips banner if it is stopped.
            App.tipTimer.Start();
            // Set the banner's text to the current tip's sumamry.
            tipLabel.Text = ((App)App.Current).CurrentTip.Summary;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTip");
            // Subscribe the OnTipUpdate function to the tipUpdate event in the app
            // class.
            App.TipUpdate += OnTipUpdate;

            // Make the ObservableCOllection reference something.
            items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            // Open a stream to the list that we want to display.
            using (StreamReader listReader = new StreamReader(App.selectedList
                .ListFile.FullName))
            {
                // Loop through the file and read data into the list.
                while (!listReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    // Create a blank item.
                    Item newItem = new Item()
                    {
                        ItemEditor = new Editor()
                        {
                            Text = listReader.ReadLine(),
                            Placeholder = "New Item",
                            IsTabStop = true,
                            AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges,
                            WidthRequest = 300
                        },
                        ItemCheckbox = new CheckBox()
                        {
                            Color = App.selectedList.ListItemColor,
                            IsChecked = bool.Parse(listReader.ReadLine())
                        }
                    };
                    // Subscribe OnTextChanged() to the new item's editor's
                    // TextChanged event.
                    newItem.ItemEditor.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
                    // Add the new item to the list.
                    items.Add(newItem);
                    // Make the ListView update.
                    OnPropertyChanged("contacts");
                }
                // Once everything is loaded, close the file.
                listReader.Close();
                ChecklistView.ItemsSource = items;
            }
        }

        ...

        // Function for when the "Add New Contact" button is clicked.
        private void OnAddNewItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a blank item.
            Item newItem = new Item()
            {
                ItemEditor = new Editor()
                {
                    Placeholder = "New Item",
                    IsTabStop = true,
                    AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges,
                    WidthRequest = 300
                },
                ItemCheckbox = new CheckBox()
                {
                    Color = App.selectedList.ListItemColor,
                    IsChecked = false
                }
            };
            // Subscribe OnTextChanged() to the new item's editor's
            // TextChanged event.
            newItem.ItemEditor.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
            // Add the new contact to the list.
            items.Add(newItem);
            // Set the "itemAdded" flag to true.
            itemAdded = true;
            // Make the ListView update.
            ChecklistView.ItemsSource = items;
            OnPropertyChanged("items");
            // Select the new item so it can be focused.
            ChecklistView.SelectedItem = items.ElementAt(items.Count - 1);
        }

        // Function for when an item is selected, used to set the focus to
        // a newly added item in the list.
        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Only runs this if an item was added (as opposed to being 
            // read in from the file).
            if (itemAdded)
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
                await Task.Delay(100); // Change the delay time if Focus() doesn't work.
                ((Item)e.SelectedItem).ItemEditor.Focus();
                ChecklistView.SelectedItem = null;
                itemAdded = false;
            }
        }

        // Function for when the text of an editor is changed.
        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the editor's text now contains a newline...
            if (((Editor)sender).Text.Contains("\n"))
            {
                // Split the string at the newline and recombine it. This
                // will get rid of the newline.
                string[] tempArray = ((Editor)sender).Text.Split('\n');
                string tempStr = "";
                foreach (string str in tempArray)
                {
                    tempStr += str;
                }
                ((Editor)sender).Text = tempStr;
                // Unfocus the editor.
                ((Editor)sender).Unfocus();
            }
            // Force the cell's size to update (it is the parent of the 
            // parent of the parent of the parent of the editor).
            ((ViewCell)((Editor)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).ForceUpdateSize();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it probably is caused by you called `ForceUpdateSize` in `OnTextChanged`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT That worked, but I had it in there because I want the cells to automatically resize to fit their content (which was also not working).

Comment: Try to call focus after ForceUpdateSize();.

Comment: I just tried that. It didn’t work, so I added an await Task.Delay() between them and now it unfocused and then focuses again.

Comment: I just added an answer and can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the ListView with a CollectionView and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Also, the CollectionView doesn't have a HasUnevenRows property, so that will have to be removed and it doesn't use cells, so the ForceUpdateSize() method will also have to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ForceUpdateSize` will cause Editor unfocus. You can put the `ForceUpdateSize` into a `Task.Run` method and call focus after `ForceUpdateSize();`.

```
private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

    //...

    await Task.Run(()=>{

        ((ViewCell)((Editor)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).ForceUpdateSize();

    });

    ((Editor)sender).Focus();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I ended up replacing the ListView with a CollectionView to try to optimize the app and that seems to have fixed the problem.